# Indentation error using result of haml_tag inside js.haml template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, ujs

in my users_helper i have the following method :

users_helper.rb

```
def status(user)
   if user.active?
      capture_haml do
         haml_tag 'span.status' do 
            haml_concat "active"
         end
      end
   else
      capture_haml do
         haml_tag 'span.status' do 
            haml_concat "inactive"
         end
      end
   end
end
```

then i have a remote link to change the user's status, so if the status is changed i want to replace my `span.status` with the result returned by `status method` which is in my `users_helper`

change_status.js.haml

```
- unless @user.errors.any? 
   plain:
      $("span.status").html("#{status(@user)}");
```

but this seem not working, when i check the error with firebug i have this :

```
Inconsistent indentation: 1 tab used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 2 spaces.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `change_status.js.haml`, you have indented the code with `two` spaces throughout the document but at one place you used `tab`.

Make sure that indentation is **uniform** in your Haml file. `Don't mix-match`, use either `two` spaces throughout the document or `tab` throughout the document. Choose one and stick to it.

**EDIT**

Also, escape the results of `status` method using `escape_javascript`.

Comment: i use always two spaces in my files, and my HAML view is correctly indented, the problem come when i change the html of span.status exactly in this line: $("span.status").html("#{status(@user)}");